# how to update one column in csv file using the mapping from another csv file using awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I need help in updating a huge csv file with 3.5 Million records. I need to update 3rd column with the mapping value from another file.

I tried reading the file and updating the 3rd column by searching the pattern in mapping file but since the actual file is having 3.5 million and mapping file is having ~1 million records, it seems to be running forever.

E.g.

Actual file:

```
123,123abc,456_def,456_def_ble,adsf,adsafdsa,123234,45645,435,12,42,afda,3435,wfg,34,345,sergf,5t4
234,234abc,5435_defg,345_def_ble,3adsaff,asdfgdsa,165434,456,435,12,42,afda,3435,wfg,34,345,sergf,5t4
```

Mapping File:

```
456_def,24_def
5435_defg,48_defg
```

Output expected:

```
123,123abc,24_def,456_def_ble,adsf,adsafdsa,123234,45645,435,12,42,afda,3435,wfg,34,345,sergf,5t4
234,234abc,48_defg,345_def_ble,3adsaff,asdfgdsa,165434,456,435,12,42,afda,3435,wfg,34,345,sergf,5t4
```

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}       # Set field separator as comma
     NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}  # Store the mapping file into the array a
     {if($3 in a) $3=a[$3]}  # Check if there is match, and change the column value
     1                       # Print the whole line
    ' mapping actualfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty straight-forward in `Awk`

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==NR{hash[$1]=$2; next}$3 in hash{$3=hash[$3]}1' mapFile actualFile
```

produces an output as you needed.

```
123,123abc,24_def,456_def_ble,adsf,adsafdsa,123234,45645,435,12,42,afda,3435,wfg,34,345,sergf,5t4
234,234abc,48_defg,345_def_ble,3adsaff,asdfgdsa,165434,456,435,12,42,afda,3435,wfg,34,345,sergf,5t4
```

To speed up things, you can change the `locale` setting to use `ASCII`,

Simply put, when using the `locale C` it will default to the server's base Unix/Linux language of `ASCII`. By default your locale is going to be internationalized and set to `UTF-8`, which can represent every character in the Unicode character set to help display any of the world's writing systems, currently over more than `110,000` unique characters, whereas with `ASCII` each character is encoded in a single byte sequence and its character set comprises of no longer than `128` unique characters. So just do

```
LC_ALL=C awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}FNR==NR{hash[$1]=$2; next}$3 in hash{$3=hash[$3]}1' mapFile actualFile
```